# Angular file upload - intercept upload

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I am using nervgh/angular-file-upload to upload files to the server. I am using a token authentication and need to intercept every call in order to attach/refresh a token when it expires. I can provide a token to file uploader like this:

```
$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'upload_endpoint', headers: { 'Authorization': access_token }
});
```

But it's not getting into the interceptor, thus I cannot replace a token with a new one when the token expires. Any chance I still can intercept?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fileUploader callback called onBeforeUploadItem that you can use.

Ref. https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API

Comment: That would mean that I need to have another token validation routine that duplicates the one in the interceptor. Do you agree?

Comment: That's what fileUploader gives you. I'm not an expert on token validation so can not help you with that. Sorry.